# awk filter values from array based on date validation and print correct output if there is match with text at START and END including match

Tags: arrays, bash, date, awk, filtering

Hi i am trying to solve this problem where i have file1 where column number $6 contain timestamp in YYYYMMDD format which is compared with current date if 7 days older , this works, but once i would like to filter it then based on ID from defined array at print output, it will print as well prefix "START" "END" which i would like to have only just for valid IDs, instead of it its printing me for all IDs from given array

case:
i have this arrays thru which i am looping in bash script

```
ARR[AB25645R874]="VAL1"
ARR[AB25320R874]="VAL2"
ARR[AB25276R874]="VAL3"
ARR[AB25172R874]="VAL4"
ARR[AB25173R874]="VAL5"
ARR[AB25048R874]="VAL6"
ARR[AB25060R874]="VAL7"

awk -v d="$(date --date="7 days ago" "+%Y%m%d")"  '($6)  < d' file1 | \
awk -v i="$ID" '{$1=$1};BEGIN{print "START"}{if (/'${ID}'/){print $0 }}END{print "END"}'
```

where ID is represented from array, eg. 25172 in file1

input: file1

```
A B 25645 FX M.1 20200514
A B 25645 FX M.1 20200514
A B 25645 FX M.1 20200514
A B 25645 FX M.1 20200514
A B 25645 FX M.1 20200514
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200429
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200421
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200429
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200421
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25172 FX M.1 20200421
A B 25173 FX M.1 20200427
A B 25173 FX M.1 20200504
A B 25173 FX M.1 20200429
A B 25048 FX M.1 20200512
A B 25048 FX M.1 20200512
A B 25048 FX M.1 20200512
A B 25048 FX M.1 20200512
A B 25048 FX M.1 20200512
A B 25060 FX M.1 20200421
```

its printing out:

```
START
END
START
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200421
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
END
START
END
START
A B 25060 FX M.1 20200421
END
START
A B 25172 FX M.1 20200421
END
START
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200429
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200421
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200429
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200423
END
START
A B 25173 FX M.1 20200427
A B 25173 FX M.1 20200504
A B 25173 FX M.1 20200429
END
```

in fact ID: timestamps for this two IDs: 25048 25645 are not valid as its not 7days older, so it should print only just as expected output:

```
START
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200421
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
END
START
A B 25060 FX M.1 20200421
END
START
A B 25172 FX M.1 20200421
END
START
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200429
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200421
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200429
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200423
END
START
A B 25173 FX M.1 20200427
A B 25173 FX M.1 20200504
A B 25173 FX M.1 20200429
END
```

i still cannot handle this where is trick to have it correctly filtered, any hints how to better it will appreciate, thank you

Comment: Strip your data and code until the problem remains. It's too confusing.

Comment: hi @Cyrus its stripped to main problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v d="$(date --date="7 days ago" "+%Y%m%d")" 'BEGIN{ i=999999 }$6 < d && i >=$3{ if(i>$3){ if (i!=999999) print "END"; print "START" }; print $0; i=$3 }END{ print "END"}' file1
```

output:

```
START
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200429
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200421
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200429
A B 25320 FX M.1 20200423
END
START
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200421
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200328
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
A B 25276 FX M.1 20200423
END
START
A B 25172 FX M.1 20200421
END
START
A B 25060 FX M.1 20200421
END
```